# "It is connected" vs "It connected"

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

I want to know the difference and when to use which construction. For instance:

> It is connected with the current situation.

> It connected with the current situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"It is connected..." means that it is currently possesses the 'connected' attribute. "Is" is present tense as opposed to the past tense of your other line. 'Connected' acts not as a verb, but an adjective. See
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adjective-and-verb-placement/

"It connected..." means that it made a connection in the past. Connected is a verb in the past tense. It could still be connected, but it might not be. At some point in the past, it was.

Comment: Thanks, @Tallima! "It is connected..." is this case so similar to Present Perfect tense, except we use "is" but not "has". Are they connected?

Comment: The difference is much more than just tense. In *it is connected*, *connected* is being used adjectivally to describe a property of something; in *it connected*, it's descibing an actual action. The grammar itself is quite different.

Comment: Jason is correct. You've got tense differences in is and connected. The is connected uses connected as an adjective, not a verb. Here's a link for further reading and understanding: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adjective-and-verb-placement/